# how to insert values through select in ssms ? and i am getting error through which i tried

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sql-insert

I tried inserting values into a table that I created but while inserting into them through select statement I am getting an error message
the code which I tried for insert is

```
create table dbo.watermarktable
(tablename varchar(255), 
watermarkvalue datetime,
);

insert into dbo.watermarktable(tablename,watermarkvalue)
("reference_value", select max(created_date) from dbo.reference_value_genc);
```

but the values were not taken and thrown an error message
and the error message is

```
Incorrect syntax near 'reference_value'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Completion time: 2021-10-28T14:29:43.2357252+01:00
```

[image]

Comment: "reference_value" should be 'reference_value'

Comment: i tried it but still the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `VALUES` or `SELECT` with `INSERT INTO`. So Change your insert like this

```
insert into dbo.watermarktable(tablename,watermarkvalue)
SELECT 'reference_value', max(created_date) from dbo.reference_value_genc;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is a bit off, change it to this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.watermarktable (tablename,watermarkvalue)
SELECT 'reference_value', max(created_date)
FROM dbo.reference_value_genc;
```